# How to run the NPM RUN BUILD

Tags: reactjs

I have for now 7 days tried to build my ReactJs project but it never works.

**quick update**,
I can do npm run build like every 50-100th time i run it, I just have to be keep running the command and waiting for it to succeed .

When I do  NPM RUN BUILD in vscode  I always get the error

> (copy plugin) Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, copyfile
> 'L:\react\Greta100Weeks\greta100weeks\notistack\src\index.d.ts' ->
> 'L:\react\Greta100Weeks\greta100weeks\notistack\dist\index.d.ts'

I tested to build on different locations to rule out that the folder or file was locked. I turn of MacAfee LiveSafe background scanning virus. I don't have any Drive syncing locking folders

I use the Windows 10 Resource Monitor to see if the notistack folder and the files are locked by some process and they are not, it's super strange. I have no backup process on that folder, Mcafee LiveSafe is turned of also

I notice that npm run build works like every 20-30 times i run the command . When I restart computer it worked one time also. It's like something is polling locking the files randomly

Another thing I can see is that the error say that the file "index.d.ts" can't be copied. I then open the notistack\dist\ folder and see a "index.d.ts" file and when I open the file in notepad++ I see this: just a bunch of NULNULNULL..........

[image]
[image]
Here I try running npm run build on a fresh fork of the notistack in the cmd window

[image]

Comment: is this the solution to your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081270/getting-error-ebusy-resource-busy-or-locked

Comment: @NidhiDadiya did not work. I use the Windows 10  Resource Monitor to see if the notistack folder and the files are locked by some process and they are not, it's super strange. I have no backup process on that folder, Mcafee LiveSafe is turned of also

Comment: why did you use .d.ts for your index file?

Comment: @DevAddict I just fork [Notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack) and download it with GitHub Desktop and do the npm run build. I dunno about the file names do you think something is wrong?

Comment: I notice that npm run build works like every 20-30 times i run the command . When I restart computer it worked one time also. It's like something is polling locking the files randomly

Comment: I can do npm run build like every 50-100th time i run it, I just have to be keep running the command and waiting for it to succeed .Windows 10 is so fucked up LOL

Comment: Your latest ss says you need to update `npm` by `npm update`

Answer (score 1):

I did what you did. Cloned repo of Notistack. did `npm i` and then `npm run build`. it worked for me.

From your screenshot, i tried to match it with mine. i found that probably you haven't installed node modules at proper place. when you clone the repo. it already creates a `notistack` folder on top of where it is located on your computer.

The differnce i found is, both your paths should partially match till `notistack` folder. In your ss, JSON is written at perfect place, but typescript path is different from mine.

so from your screenshot, i think you should try doing `npm i` at

```
L:\react\Greta100Weeks\greta100weeks\notistack
```

I hope it makes sense !

Comment: Thanks, here a [screenshot](https://snipboard.io/9L2WmO.jpg) showing I do run the command in "L:\react\Greta100Weeks\greta100weeks\notistack
"

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "haven't installed node modules at proper place."

Comment: I hope when trying again with `npm run build` you're removing the typedoc.json file. and also I see there are some node modules in the parent folder too. can you try putting notistack folder at some other location?

Comment: When I originally cloned from GitHub the Notistack was saved [here](https://snipboard.io/ft5G3L.jpg) . Then I copy the folder into the "L:\react\Greta100Weeks" just for testing, maybe it would work better if the notistack was under the same node_modules folder as the app , dunno just testing

Comment: Good. So go there in vs code(git/notistack/) and do `npm run build` is it working there?

Comment: if you want notistack to be there at greta100weeks. try cloning there. or else copy folder there, remove node modules and do `npm i` again.

Comment: ok thanks, I do "npm link" on notistack so it can be located anywhere i guess. ok now running npm run build from the git folder...But I have [problem with nmp link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136755/cant-set-breakpoints-on-npm-linked-library). Usually I dont have this much problem really heheh

Comment: ok it failed again from the git folder, here's a [screenshot](https://snipboard.io/LPxIlo.jpg). so frustation I was thinking to reinstall laptop really

Comment: Running npm run build again error [hmm](https://snipboard.io/R0wJBY.jpg)

Comment: I will as you suggest @Nidhi Dadiya - remove node modules and do npm i again

Comment: do `npm i` too if you're removing node modules

Comment: ok after delete node_modules and doing nmp i and then again running npm run build, i get the same error ..Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, copyfile 'L:\git\notist..... ok now laptop go out the window LOL

Comment: will start laptop in windows safe mode now and try running the "npm run build"

Comment: Result after starting laptop in Windows Safe Mode and running npm run build is that it failed at first attempt and it success on second attempt here is a [screenshot](https://snipboard.io/BbNrvK.jpg). One should be happy with that NOOOOT, WTF is going on.  This was on on the L:/git/notistack but on the other copied L:\react\Greta100Weeks\greta100weeks\notistack it failed. I have no clue where to go from here...My Facebook please be kind https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100016526263449

Comment: I did a bug report at [npm](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3774)